# Textplot in for loops and adding descriptions to plots

Tags: r, for-loop, plot, bar-chart

I made the following loop to get a graph with two plots and a description for each column. The plotting works perfectly. But the description will only show in the first plot.

In addition I am using textplot for the description, but I would be  happy to hear other suggestions to make a prettier description. I don't like the font and the fact that the text gets cut off in some cases.

PS: I'm sorry I can't upload the inputs as they are confidential

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(nlme)
library(AER)
library(ggpubr)
library(mlogit)
library(margins)
library(varhandle)
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(reshape2)
library(janitor)
library(gplots)

for (col in 3:ncol(KAK)) {
  layout(matrix(c(1,1,2,3),2,2, byrow = TRUE), heights = c(1,2))
  textplot(KAK2[1,col], halign = "center")
  barplot(table(VAK$Art, VAK[,col]), beside = FALSE,
        col = c("darkolivegreen1","plum"),
        xlab = "Rang",
        ylab = "Anzahl Rangzuordnung",
        border = F,
        main = "VAK",
        legend.text = c("AK","Revision AK"))
  barplot(table(KAK$Art, KAK[,col]), beside = FALSE,
        col = c("coral1","darkgoldenrod1"),
        xlab = "Rang",
        ylab = "Anzahl Rangzuordnung",
        border = F,
        main = "KAK",
        legend.text = c("AK","Revision AK"))
}
```

Comment: The input and library statements are missing so no one except you can run this.  Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page which provides info on asking questions.

Comment: Here's some guidance for creating a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example